# Unity can't compile iOS project undefined symbols

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am unable to compile my unity iOS project in xcode. I get this error with no further detail. How can I find out what is going wrong?

```
Undefined symbols:
```

[image]

Comment: Click the error, you should see the details in the middle area.

Comment: Nothing shows up when I click it

Comment: The last icon above the issue list is Report navigator. It should have a Build item under Unity-iPhone. It will lead you to complete build log. There you can find the same error, open context menu and select "Expand All Transcripts".